# Run a systemd unit in a specified network namespace

Tags: linux, systemd, network-namespace

I would like to instruct systemd to 'run a unit' in a specified, pre-existing network namespace, in particular to start the unit's process(es) in the namespace.

Comment: You can do this very easily with `JoinsNamespaceOf=` if systemd created the namespace for the other process.

Comment: Yeah I spotted that, but systemd did not create the namespace. (There is no other process involved). Is the approach to create a unit to encapsulate the creation of the namespace, and then refer to that unit name in JoinsNamespaceOf?

Comment: You're probably at the level of complexity where you should just start using containers via some existing technology, rather than trying to roll them yourself.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I'm simply trying to do this to debug a problem. I will start the process outside of systemd for the purpose of debugging.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like it's now possible to do this in systemd 242 via the `NetworkNamespacePath` option: [announcement](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/d4d74d0fc0eeff7bfe56f81ea06ea0399bab095c/NEWS#L518-L520).

Check out the docs for use it [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#NetworkNamespacePath=).

Answer (score 3):

systemd is not fully compatible with network namespace as the issues
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2741, may add some other key words 
 like ExecStart to add network namespace switch into namespace before running service.

Comment: The `NetworkNamespacePath` option was introduced in 2019.  Consequently, I believe this answer is out of date and/or misleading, and the answer should be updated or deleted.